# Docker. Build NDK project. The detected version of Ninja () is less than the version of Ninja required by CMake (1.3)

Tags: android, docker, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have project that recently start using ndk. I have CI worked with Docker. After adding ndk to my project I added ndk to docker file, however for now I see problem with Ninja version.
Here's log output

```
-- Check for working C compiler: /android-ndk-linux/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
CMake Error:
  The detected version of Ninja () is less than the version of Ninja required
  by CMake (1.3).
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile generation of cmake failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /android-ndk-linux/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -- broken
CMake Error at /sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler
  "/android-ndk-linux/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang" is not
  able to compile a simple test program.
```

Did anyone faced with the same problem? Here's link for my docker file on docker hub https://cloud.docker.com/repository/docker/relgang/ndkfastlane

Comment: try to clean your build dir, see https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/issues/1227#issuecomment-311573742

Comment: @shizhen Do you mean clean ninja? ninja clean commmand

Comment: Your dockerfile link doesn't work. It redirects to the docker hub home page.